# SpringBoot Rest API: Works as Java Application, fails when deployed on tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a Springboot project and it has a api which I can invoke from postman.
When I run the application using Main Class I'm able to hit the endpoint and get response.

But if I deploy it on tomcat using war of project the same endpoint says 404!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple possibilities

1. You didn't extended your application class to SpringBootServletInitializer. In this case, spring boot application will not be deployed to tomcat. To fix this add "extends SpringBootServletInitializer" to your main application class
2. You are hitting wrong url. Make sure you append your aplication name to url. Example - if http://localhost:8080/data works in your local, and your application name is app, you have to hit http://{{serverip:port}}/app/data when deployed
3. There is something wrong in application properties like DB configured is local and not accessible from tomcat etc. To check such issues, check your tomcat log file (/{{tomcat dir}}/logs/catalina.out